# Encoding String using an encoding code

Tags: java

Following is my code snippet:

```
 for (int i=0;i<(in.length());i++)
    {
        char e=cop.charAt(i);
        if (e==' ')
        {
            sav=sav+" ";
            continue;
        }
        int n=(int)e;
        if (n>=(91-ef))
        {
            //here is where the statement should be
            continue;
        }    
        n=n+ef;
        sav=sav+((char)n);
    }
```

in: String entered by the user

ef: encoding factor entered by the user

sav: in which I'm storing my modified String

Here what I need to do is input a string (word or sentence) in upper case and increase the ASCII value of each character of the string by an encoding factor entered by the user and print the respective character at the new ASCII value. Spaces will remain spaces and if the character should exceed 'Z', it'll start again from 'A'. It's the last part I'm having problem with. There should be one statement at the place I've commented in the above code but I can't figure out what it should be. Please help?

Here's an example what I need to do:

INPUT: tommy

OUTPUT: YTRRD (when the encoding factor is 5)

Comment: Hint: "tommy" is not upper case.

Comment: I know, I've converted it to upper case earlier in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would add first and then check it using using characters instead of raw numbers.

```
e = Character.toUpperCase(e);
e += 5;
if (e > 'Z')
   e -= 'Z' + 1 - 'A';
sav += e;
```

or using a constant.

```
static final int LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET = 'Z' + 1 - 'A';

// in code
e = Character.toUpperCase(e);
e += 5;
if (e > 'Z')
   e -= LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET;
sav += e;
```

Comment: Please explain the 4th line?

Comment: @ShinjineeMaiti Suppose that `e` = `'Z'` and `ef = 1`. This line takes the value of `e` back to `'A'` instead of `'Z'+1`.

Comment: It subtracts 26 without having to calculate how many letters there are. `'Z' + 1` becomes `'A'`, `'Z' + 2` becomes `'B'` etc.

Comment: To resolve any question, [put the result of the expression…in a constant with a name that explains the purpose](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractVariable.html).

Comment: @TomBlodget Equations are not as readable to some people.  English would be better.

Comment: @TomBlodget Not sure if it more or less readable, but have included it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, this should work:

```
if (n>=(91-ef))
{
     n = 64 + (n+ef-90) -ef;
}
```

- There is no need for `continue`.
- `n+ef` is the final "normal" value, eg: Y=89, so, on adding 5, it becomes 94.
- `-90` to check by how much it is greater than 90, i.e, 4 (in case of Y).
- `64 + (n+ef-90)` - Then add that number to 64, i.e. 64+4 = 68 = D
- `-ef` as you add `ef` after that. The line after this piece of code is : `n=n+ef;`. That would make 68+4 = 72 = H. But you already have the needed char, i.e., D, so you subtract `ef` so it becomes 68-5 = 63. Then, in the next line, you add it to get 63+5 = 68 = D.

Comment: Didn't get the last bullet. Please re-explain?

Comment: @ShinjineeMaiti Did you get it now?

Comment: Now I get what you mean, but if you notice I've given a 'continue' after that so no need for the last bullet. Thanks though.

Comment: @ShinjineeMaiti You should not use `continue`. If you do, then the line `sav=sav+((char)n);` will not be executed, and the char will not be added to `sav`

Comment: I would directly convert that ASCII value to char in the same line itself

Comment: @ShinjineeMaiti Well yes, You may!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

1. `e` is a character in ASCII code. Convert it to a `[0-25]` value using `e - 'A'`
2. Then add `ef`
3. As the result can exceed 25 (i.e `e > 'Z'`), use a modulo 26
4. Finally, add `'A'` to the result in order to convert the value back to a `['A'-'Z']` value.

Code :

```
String in = "TOMMY";
String sav="";
int ef = 5;

for (int i=0;i<(in.length()); i++) {
  char e=in.charAt(i);
  if (e==' ')
  {
    sav=sav+" ";
  } else {
    sav += (char) ('A' + ((e - 'A' + ef) % 26));
  }
}

System.out.println(sav);
```

result :

> YTRRD

- Note : Using `String+=` is bad. use a `StringBuilder` instead.
- Note : Replace `(e - 'A' + ef)` with `(e - 'A' + ef + 26)` if you want to enable negative values for `ef`.